# Reference/Documentation for GWT Elemental webRTC api

Tags: gwt, webrtc, gwt-elemental

I am trying to create a file sharing application by using [GWT Elemental](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/elemental.html) webRTC api,

but I can't find any relevant references/documentation regarding GWT Elemental webRTC api,

moreover is GWT Elemental api being maintained anymore ?,

will using GWT Elemental api be a good idea as per its current state of implementation?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Elemental` library hasn't been updated since it was released. As a result some of the classes and function might not work as the underlying specs and browser implementations have changed since then.

Nevertheless for most of the stuff you can follow the official browser docs of WebRTC (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/). The `Elemental` library "only" defines `JavascriptOverlay` wrappers for the native classes and functions.

I don't specifically about the state of the WebRTC classes in Elemental but if something is missing you can either implement your own `JavascriptOverlay` wrapper (copy the existing implementation) or just use pure `JSNI` to call the native functions.

Regarding the future of `Elemental` refer to this thread: https://plus.google.com/106517533977565466416/posts/9Mgax1nuncF